# Find CamelCase / WikiWord words using regex in Notepad++ (Np++)

Tags: notepad++, regex, markdown

I need a regex statement to find any words formatted in CamelCase. Examples include:

- CamelCase.
- Trunk_Note.
- Med-Dr.Zung.
- _MyToDo-Housework.
- _MyToDo-Vacation_Cancun
- iOS_GReader

Key points:

- The first character can be any character that is valid in a Windows OS filename.
- Any character can be any character that is valid in a Windows OS filename including `.`.
- The word will be delimited by a preceding  (space), `(`, or `[` and followed by a  (space), `)`, or `]`.

Why? I use an iOS app called Trunk Notes to maintain extensive notes on all aspects of my life (1000+ topics covering 10+ years of work, family, and personal content). Trunk Notes uses Markdown for content formatting but has a specific problem with my CamelCase words. When placed inside a link label or title, e.g. iOS_WriteRoom, the Markdown engine chokes and generates broken HTML. Underscores (`_`) in the words also confuse the engine. The simplist solution is to precede the offending word with `/`, e.g. /iOS_WriteRoom.

I began making manual edits but realize regex should work for me. So my regex solution will look for the matching pattern and prepend a `/` if a `/` has not already been prepended.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `Trunk_Note` and `Med-Dr.Zung` are *not* camel case, they're [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) or mixed camel / snake case. The only camel case example you have is "CamelCase". The others contain underscores, dashes, or other punctuation to separate words, where camel case only uses capitalization: `TrunkNote`, `MedDrZung`, `MyToDoHousework`, `MyToDoVacationCancun`, `iOSGReader`. Food for thought!

Answer (score 3):

This is particularly hard because you don't seem to be following a CamelCase style where the first letter is always capitalized and you are allowing multiple, consecutive capitals. The only definition that would capture all of your examples would be

```
Words containing at least two non-consecutive capital letters separated by 
lower case letters.
```

This means that it will also capture patterns like `foObaR` which are not really CamelCase and might not be what you need.

Anyway, the regular expression below matches all your examples*:

```
 [\(\[ ]([_\-\.a-z]*[A-Z][_\-\.a-zA-Z]+[A-Z]+[_\-\.a-z]*)[\)\] ]
  ----- - -------- - ---  ----------- - --- - -------- -- -----
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |  |  |     |    ||   |> Right boundary: 
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |  |  |     |    ||         ),] or space
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |  |  |     |    ||----> Close capture
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |  |  |     |    |-----> 0 or more
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |  |  |     |----------> Character class:
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |  |  |                   ,-,., or a to z
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |  |  |----------------> 1 or more    
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |  |-------------------> A to Z       
    |   |     |    |  |        |      |----------------------> 1 or more 
    |   |     |    |  |        |-----------------------------> Character class:
    |   |     |    |  |                                        ,-,., a to z 
    |   |     |    |  |                                        or A to Z
    |   |     |    |  |--------------------------------------> Capital letter
    |   |     |    |-----------------------------------------> 0 or more
    |   |     |----------------------------------------------> Character class:
    |   |                                                      ,-,., and a to z
    |   |----------------------------------------------------> Open capture
    |--------------------------------------------------------> Left boundary:
                                                               (,[ or space
```

* I think. I have not used notepad++ myself but [their site](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/) says they use [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/). The above is a PCRE that matches all your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Craig --

I don't think the one above will work for all your cases in Notepad++.  If you haven't found an answer yet, try this variation:

```
([(\[\s])([a-z0-9_.\-]*[A-Z]+[a-z0-9_.\-]+[A-Z]+[a-z0-9_.\-]*)([)\]\s])
```

This will also match the boundary characters -- `[]`, `()`, or space (`\s`) -- to make sure you're getting only the WikiWords you want to catch.  Use that string in the Find field and this one in Replace:

```
\1/\2\3
```

... and you should end up with (e.g.) `(/MyWikiWords)` in place of `(MyWikiWords)`.

---

If you have some WikiWords that appear outsidet the context of brackets or parentheses, you could try this Search:

```
\b([a-z0-9_.\-]*[A-Z]+[a-z0-9_.\-]+[A-Z]+[a-z0-9_.\-]*)\b
```

... and this in Replace:

```
/\1
```

... which use the word boundary (`\b`) regex.